# Trying to get clones form text input values to stay after refresh with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im making a sunbed app,every box means 2 sunbeds,i doubleclick box and change background color, every color means the actual situation of the sunbed but localstorage is only working for my original item but not working for my clones.I need to save all my clones forms input text and background changes,how can i get it
workfile: https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/NWyJdVx

```
<input type="text"  style="height:17px" id="qty" name="qty" size="3"  name="formulario" value="">






document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("qty").onkeyup = store;
    document.getElementById("qty").onload = getValue();
});


//store value after changes
function store(){
    var text = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    localStorage.setItem("qty",text);
}
//local storage to keep values after refresh
function getValue(){
    var storedText = localStorage.getItem("qty");
    alert(storedText);
    if(storedText != null){
        document.getElementById("qty").value = storedText; 
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("qty").value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code once, here is [workable example](https://codepen.io/maheshmthorat/pen/JjLPEox).

```js
let variable1;
    for (var x=1;x<96 ;x++)
    {
        $(".beach_wrapper").append($(".sunbed").first().clone(
            ).attr("id","clon_"+x));

        $("#clon_1,#clon_2" ).attr('style', 'background:orange;');
        $("#clon_10,#clon_11,#clon_22,#clon_23,#clon_34,#clon_35,#clon_46,#clon_47,#clon_58,#clon_59,#clon_70,#clon_71").attr('style','background:honeydew;');
    }

    $('.toggle').dblclick(function () {  let step = $(this).data('actual-step') || 1;
        $(this).addClass('step'+ step);
        $(this).data('actual-step', step + 1 );
    });

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.getElementById("qty").onload = getValue();
    });

    var localStorageArr = {};
    $("input.sunbed").keyup(function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        var inpId = $(this).attr('id');
        localStorage.setItem(inpId, text);
    });

//local storage to keep values after refresh
function getValue(){
    $( "input.sunbed" ).each(function( index ) {
        var inpID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).val(localStorage.getItem(inpID));
    });
}
```

```css
.beach_wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  max-width: 100%; 
   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 120px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px ;
  grid-template-rows: 90px 90px 90px 90px 90px 110px 100px 90px;
  gap: 0px 0px;  
   
  transform:scale(70%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  }

body { 
    
   display: flex;
  align-items: center ;
  height: 100vh;
 
  background:honeydew;
}
 



.sunbed {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: orange;
  border-color: black;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left:12px;
  margin-top:15px;
 
  }

  .sunbed.step1 {
  background:LightSeaGreen; 
    /*ocupado*/
     }

.sunbed.step2 {
  background: red;
  /*pagado*/
  }
.sunbed.step3 {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, DarkCyan 50%); 
  /*ocupado con 3 hamacas cada lado*/
      }
.sunbed.step4 {
  background:linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, green 50%); 
  /*ocupado 1 persona sola*/
     }


.sunbed.step5{
  background:orange;
  /*hamaca off*/
  
}
.sunbed.step6{
  background:green;
}
.sunbed.step7{
  background:LightSeaGreen;
}
.sunbed.step8{
  background:red;
}
.sunbed.step9{
  background:linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, DarkCyan 50%); 
  /*ocupado con 3 hamacas cada lado*/
}

.sunbed.step10{
  background:linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, green 50%); 
  /*ocupado 1 persona sola*/
    }
.sunbed.step11{
  background:green;
}

.form input{
  background-color: #FFEFD5;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  text-align:center;
  zoom: 100%;
  touch-action: none; 
  }



@media only screen and (min-width: 384px) and (max-width: 767px) { /* Your Styles... */ }










  


#clon_10,#clon_11,#clon_22,#clon_23,#clon_34,#clon_35,#clon_46,#clon_47,#clon_58,#clon_59,#clon_70,#clon_71{
 
 border: 0px solid;
  
  }
#clon_72,#clon_73,#clon_74,#clon_75,#clon_76,#clon_77,#clon_78,#clon_79,#clon_80,#clon_81,#clon_82,#clon_83,#clon_84,#clon_85,#clon_86,#clon_87,#clon_88,#clon_89,#clon_90,#clon_91,#clon_92,#clon_93,#clon_94,#clon_95{
  
  width: 75px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 30px;

  
}


.h1{
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="beach_wrapper">
    <div class="sunbedtoggle">
        <input type="text"  style="height:17px" id="qty" name="qty" size="3" class="sunbed" name="formulario" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/maheshmthorat/pen/JjLPEox

Comment: Hi maheshmthorat,thanks very much for your help.its very important to me, im trying to apply your code to my actual code work, its works for save form info but im lossing my sunbeds boxes at the same time if i apply.can you tell me why?At the same time i need to safe the sunbed.step background color i left, is possible to safe all the info in general?I add picture to let you see what i need https://ibb.co/bPmJ5YF  . My work; codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/NWyJdVx . Thank you very much